# Magento 2: New order mail notification to admin

Tags: magento2, order-email, adminnotification

In my store New order mail notification successfully sending to customers but not sending to admin.

I know this method can help to send a BCC to entered emails

> Store->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails->Send Order Email Copy To

But in this case, email contents only matches to customers not for admins.

Answer (score 6):

Magento 2 allows sending a copy of orders to an email besides the customer's email. It can be done thru **Stores** -> **Settings** -> **Configuration** -> ***Send Order Email Copy To***

In the latest version of Magento, this setting is here

**Store >> Settings >> Configuration >> Sales >> Sales Email >> Send Order Email Copy To**

Answer (score 2):

There is no build-in function in Magento, you may need to find some extension or code it yourself.

Comment: Then why is there this configuration in the Admin?
Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Send Order Email Copy To

Comment: @BunyaminInan : As I understand the question, he want to send a different email with content dedicated for admin, not just a copy of the customer email.

Comment: you can use extension of [recent sales notification](https://www.mageants.com/recent-sales-notification-for-magento-2.html)